# how to find a time duration between two latitudes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem while i calculate specific time duration and distance between two latlong in google map ,  Calculating distance is Easy . But the duration i cant .How to calculate duration between two latlong using javascript?

Here is my distance calculation code :

```
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
        var data = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000;
        return data.toFixed(2) + " Kms";
    }
```

p1 & p2 is some latlong.

If any other function like google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) for calculating duration?

Anyone know revert back to me..

Comment: How do you define the duration between locations? Is it the difference in time zones? Or some hypothetical travel time?

Comment: i need some particular region only sir

Comment: "Duration" still undefined. Please specify

Answer (score 1):

If with "duration" you mean the time needed by the rotating earth to pass from p1's meridian to p2's meridian, you don't need a Google Maps API function:

```
var d = ( p2.lng() - p1.lng() ) / 360;  // difference 
d = 360 * ( d - Math.floor(d) ); // to reduce it to 0..360
var duration = 23.93444 * d;     // multiply with length of sidereal day
                                 // --> gives result in hours
```